# Load, modify, then save testng-results.xml

Tags: xml, selenium, groovy, testng

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" ignored="0" total="1" passed="1">
  <reporter-output>
  </reporter-output>
  <suite name="Gradle suite">
    <groups>
      <group name="smoke-ui-forms">
        <method name="fp17CompleteForm" class="ui.forms.fp17CompleteFormXX1011"/>
      </group> <!-- smoke-ui-forms -->
    </groups>
    <test name="Gradle test">
      <class name="ui.forms.fp17CompleteFormXX1011">
        <test-method status="PASS" name="beforeClassSpec" ">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- beforeClassSpec -->
        <test-method status="PASS" name="fp17CompleteForm">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
          <attributes>
            <attribute name="test">
              <![CDATA[XX-1011]]>
            </attribute> <!-- test -->
          </attributes>
        </test-method> <!-- fp17CompleteForm -->
        <test-method status="PASS" name="cleanupSpec">
          <reporter-output>
          </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- cleanupSpec -->
      </class> <!-- ui.forms.fp17CompleteFormXX1011 -->
    </test> <!-- Gradle test -->
  </suite> <!-- Gradle suite -->
</testng-results>
```

Given the above XML, I am trying to load the file, modify it to remove all test-methods that have a name that equals beforeClassSpec.

Groovy Script

```groovy
def xmlFile = new File("../../../build/reports/tests/test/testng-results.xml")
def xml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)
def nodes = xml.suite.test.class.'test-method'
nodes
        .findAll { it.'@name' == 'beforeClassSpec' }
        .each { nodes.remove(it) }
```

This code does succeed in removing the beforeClassSpec from my `nodes` def but they remain in the `xml` def.

I also tried this

```groovy
def xmlFile = new File("../../../build/reports/tests/test/testng-results.xml")
def xml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)
xml.suite.test.class.'test-method'
        .findAll { it.'@name' == 'beforeClassSpec' }
        .each { xml.remove(it) }
```

I also tried using xmlSlurper, and it fails to read the file properly and only returns the `CDATA` node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.each { it.parent().remove(it) }`

```
def nodes = xml.suite.test.class.'test-method'
nodes
        .findAll { it.'@name' == 'beforeClassSpec' }
        .each { it.parent().remove(it) }
        
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

Comment: Intelij shows `parent()` as no declaration, but the script runs and works as desired.

Comment: according to groovy doc - it's public: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html#parent()

Comment: yeah, I think there is something misconfigured with my intelij which is another problem I'll have to dig into at some point.